# Are there 100 points that are part of every half-density part of the plane?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, ramsey-theory, erdos

> Is there a configuration $P$ that consists of 100 points of the plane such that every $X\subset\mathbb R^2$ whose density is half contains an isometric copy of $P$?

I am deliberately being vague about what I mean by density half, but the definition should include the Lebesgue-measure and some limit.
Note that if we reduce half to 0.22, then the answer is no already for $|P|=2$.
If we increase half to 0.991, then the answer is yes by the pigeonhole principle.
If instead of density, you want to two-color the plane and find a monochromatic copy of $P$, then we get an unsolved problem by P Erdős, R.L Graham, P Montgomery, B.L Rothschild, J Spencer, E.G Straus.

Comment: We have an Erdos tag??

Comment: We can try to find some necessary conditions which the set $P$ satisfies as follows. Let $N=99$, $\bar N:=\{0,1,\dots,N\}$ and $P=\{(x_i,y_i):i\in\bar N\}$. For each $r>0$ consider the subset $S_p$ of the plane $\mathbb R^2$, consisting of vertical strips $[nr,(n+1)r)\times\mathbb R$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$.  Then $S_p$ contains a shifted and rotated by $\alpha_r$ copy of $P$ (it is easy to see that we can ignore the reflections). ...

Comment: ... That is there exist a vector $(x_r,y_r)$ of unit length and $s_r\in\mathbb R$ such that the set $P_r-s_r$, where $P_=\{x_ix_r+y_iy_r:i\in\bar N\}$, belongs to the union of halfintervals $[nr,(n+1)r)$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$. Moreover, we can get rid of $s_r$ as follows. Assume that $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ and for any $i\in \bar N$ pick a unique integer number $n_i^r$ such that $z_i=x_ix_r+y_iy_r-2n^r_i$ belongs to $(-r,r)$. Then the required $s_r$ exists iff $|z_i-z_j|<r$ for each $i,j\in \bar N$.